# expdp on a different SID and use of EXCLUDE, INCLUDE and CONTENT switch

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, export, datapump

I am trying to import a db into my local xe instance. I have a problem in that it is greater than 11GB and things fall over. My db has audit tables (courtesy of envers). I do not need this data.

Two questions here:

- can I expdp table structures and not data for the aud_ tables that are my audit tables
- can I expdp on a different SID. My SID is not orcl but orcllo (for historical reason)

For the second question I have done the following but

```
sqlplus / as sysdba@orcllo
alter user MY_DB identified by MY_PASS ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY db_dumps AS '/tmp/db_dumps';
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY db_dumps TO MY_DB;
```

but when I run expdp I get an error about db_dumps not being found.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q.1**:

You can use '**EXCLUDE**' or '**INCLUDE'** switch during oracle impdp (data pump) to escape/include few tables.

The following code shows how they can be used as command line parameters.

```
impdp scott/tiger@db10g schemas=SCOTT exclude=TABLE:"IN ('EMP', 'DEPT')" directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=SCOTT.dmp logfile=expdpSCOTT.log
```

Same can be done during export as well:

```
expdp scott/tiger@db10g schemas=SCOTT exclude=TABLE:"IN ('EMP', 'DEPT')" directory=TEST_DIR
```

CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY switch should be used if you indeed want  to create structure on target schema/db.

**Q.2:**

You can not use expdp / impdp on a different SID as is but via DB Link route (using **NETWORK_LINK** switch).

However, i think, Ans-1 should address your real problem due to Oracle XE limitations.  Moreover, there may be performance issues due to cross network/DB data flow.

Both the local and remote users require the IMP_FULL_DATABASE role granted to them.

```
impdp test/test@db10g tables=SCOTT.EMP network_link=REMOTE_SCOTT directory=TEST_DIR logfile=impdpSCOTT.log remap_schema=SCOTT:TEST
```

HTH

Check the following for more options with data pump:

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php

Comment: exclude=TABLE:"IN ('EMP', 'DEPT')" - won't this skip the table structure also? I think CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY should be used to export only the structure and not the data ?

Comment: Yes, Ankit. To be precise, CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY should be used if you indeed want  to create structure on target schema/db. In this case, the guy's real need was to get rid of uploading large audit data which, i think, was met with just EXCLUDE.